# Stripping Leading Zero

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, integer

I'm using the code below to set a user PIN in AD extensionAttribute3. This works pefectly well for digits that are 1-9. However, if someone enters zeros first, they are stripped out. Entering zeros after the first digit isn't being stripped, just leading zeros. 
How can I stop the zero stripping from happening? It would be plausible that someone could set a PIN of 037475, which would be a valid PIN, but would end up getting stripped to 37475.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim PIN As Integer
        Dim ADName As String = GetLogonName()
        Dim OSlanguage As ADProperties = Language()
        If EnterPIN.Text.Length < 4 Then
            MsgBox(OSlanguage.PINError2, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, OSlanguage.PINError1)
            EnterPINLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf (CheckConsecutiveChars(EnterPIN.Text, 4)) Then
            MsgBox(OSlanguage.PINError3, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, OSlanguage.PINError1)
            EnterPINLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Else
            PIN = Integer.Parse(EnterPIN.Text)
            Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry()
            Dim dirSearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
            dirSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" & ADName & "))"
            dirSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
            Dim searchResults As SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()
            If Not searchResults Is Nothing Then
                Dim dirEntryResults As New DirectoryEntry(searchResults.Path)
                SetADProperty(dirEntryResults, "extensionAttribute3", PIN)
                dirEntryResults.CommitChanges()
                dirEntryResults.Close()
                MsgBox(OSlanguage.Success3, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, OSlanguage.Success1)
                Form1_Load(Me, New System.EventArgs)
            End If
            dirEntry.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: remove `PIN = Integer.Parse(EnterPIN.Text)` conversion to int

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(EnterPin.text)

Comment: Convert it back to a string with, say, String.Format("{0:0000}", PIN)

Comment: I would like to point out that this code is very badly written, in the sense that -> Give your buttons a name, so you know what it does without doubleclicking it in a designer; Use TryParse on integers if you are parsing, use try catch block in sensitive code, do not ever recall the Form_Load method (it's there to load, 1 time usage), new System.EventArgs can also be written as System.EventArgs.Empty, don't handle all the code in a click event, but extract it to proper handler classes, so you can reuse your code later on...

Comment: @Icepickle - While I agree that the code needs to be refactored, the OP asked for help, not to be flogged. I don't think your criticism is especially helpful, nor do I think it encourages others who may be seeking help to share their code. I think you could have been more tactful in pointing out some of the shortcomings of his design.

Comment: It was my intention to give constructive critic, but the comment box is so small, i can delete it, in case it is seen as flogging :)

Comment: I know the code problably isn't perfect, or anywhere close. This is the first VB.NET application I've ever written, and I'm really just leaning as I go (no budget for training course), by pulling different code from different sites and hashing it together. Basically I was asked 2 weeks ago if we could find someway for users to update certain aspects of their profile with certain information, formatted in a specific way. Writing our own application in visual basic was the cheapest, (and most fun for me) way to go, rather than buying a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim PIN As String = ""
    Dim ADName As String = GetLogonName()
    Dim OSlanguage As ADProperties = Language()
    If EnterPIN.Text.Length < 4 Then
        MsgBox(OSlanguage.PINError2, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, OSlanguage.PINError1)
        EnterPINLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf (CheckConsecutiveChars(EnterPIN.Text, 4)) Then
        MsgBox(OSlanguage.PINError3, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, OSlanguage.PINError1)
        EnterPINLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Else
        PIN = EnterPIN.Text.Trim 'Will trim spaces only
        Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry()
        Dim dirSearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
        dirSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" & ADName & "))"
        dirSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
        Dim searchResults As SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()
        If Not searchResults Is Nothing Then
            Dim dirEntryResults As New DirectoryEntry(searchResults.Path)
            SetADProperty(dirEntryResults, "extensionAttribute3", PIN) '<-- Attention, if your class supports Integer, it needs to change to string now
            dirEntryResults.CommitChanges()
            dirEntryResults.Close()
            MsgBox(OSlanguage.Success3, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, OSlanguage.Success1)
            Form1_Load(Me, New System.EventArgs)
        End If
        dirEntry.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to use leading zeros, you just need to declare the value as type of String instead of integer and perhaps you need to setup the textbox to only accept numbers as keys.

Comment: Shouldn't trim come before checking the length of the value (first if)?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed the issue. I have the textbox setup for numbers only using the following code. This also stops anyone from using space, so there should be no need to use trim: '    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles EnterPIN.KeyPress
        If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) And Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub'

Answer (score 1):

You will want to read the value as a string instead of as an integer.